# UUID1 from UTC Timestamp in Python?

Tags: python

The problem goes like this:

My application is deployed on a remote server with different timezone and I want to generate a uuid1 against UTC timestamp. I can't find a way to generate uuid1 from any given timestamp. The reason I want to do this is that I don't want to get into the hassle of calculating my local time where my local time does not observe Daylight saving time and the remote server does and a result the presentation logic becomes cumbersome.

The limitation is that the Timestamp needs to be stored as uuid1. Any idea or workaround for this will be higly appreciated.

Comment: `The limitation is that the Timestamp needs to be stored as uuid1.`  What does this mean?  A timestamp is not a uuid.  A uuid is generated via well-known algorithms; they are not transposable with timestamps.  If by uuid1 you refer to a version 1 uuid, you can see that it depends on the MAC address: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: This is because it needs to be stored in Cassandra where the entries are sorted by TimeUUIDType which is uuid1. It can later be converted into Timestamp using a well known algorithm

Comment: @cheeso - uuid type 1 uses both mac address and timestamp.  see the rfc http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the UUID class will do the bit-juggling if you give it the right fragments - http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html

to get the right components you can copy the the uuid1 code from python2.7:

```
def uuid1(node=None, clock_seq=None):
        """Generate a UUID from a host ID, sequence number, and the current time.
        If 'node' is not given, getnode() is used to obtain the hardware
        address.  If 'clock_seq' is given, it is used as the sequence number;
        otherwise a random 14-bit sequence number is chosen."""
    # When the system provides a version-1 UUID generator, use it (but don't
    # use UuidCreate here because its UUIDs don't conform to RFC 4122).
    if _uuid_generate_time and node is clock_seq is None:
        _buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
        _uuid_generate_time(_buffer)
        return UUID(bytes=_buffer.raw)
    global _last_timestamp
    import time
    nanoseconds = int(time.time() * 1e9)
    # 0x01b21dd213814000 is the number of 100-ns intervals between the
    # UUID epoch 1582-10-15 00:00:00 and the Unix epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
    timestamp = int(nanoseconds//100) + 0x01b21dd213814000L
    if _last_timestamp is not None and timestamp <= _last_timestamp:
        timestamp = _last_timestamp + 1
    _last_timestamp = timestamp
    if clock_seq is None:
        import random
        clock_seq = random.randrange(1<<14L) # instead of stable storage
    time_low = timestamp & 0xffffffffL
    time_mid = (timestamp >> 32L) & 0xffffL
    time_hi_version = (timestamp >> 48L) & 0x0fffL
    clock_seq_low = clock_seq & 0xffL
    clock_seq_hi_variant = (clock_seq >> 8L) & 0x3fL
    if node is None:
        node = getnode()
    return UUID(fields=(time_low, time_mid, time_hi_version,
                        clock_seq_hi_variant, clock_seq_low, node), version=1)
```

all you need to do is copy+paste that and modify the timestamp part to use a fixed value (you can ignore the last_timestamp part if you know that your times are distinct - that is just to avoid duplicates when the clock resolution is insufficient).

Answer (score 3):

The Cassandra driver for Python now has a function for this very purpose:

```
cassandra.util.uuid_from_time()
```

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/util.html#cassandra.util.uuid_from_time

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to extract a Unix timestamp from a UUID v1:

```
def uuid1_unix_timestamp(uuid_):
    '''
    Extract timestamp from UUID1.

    Params
    ------
    uuid_ : uuid.UUID
        UUID v1 instance.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        Unix timestamp.
    '''
    import datetime as dt

    # UUID v1 timestamp is measured from [00:00:00, 1 October 1582][1].
    #
    # [1]: https://quora.com/Why-UUID-v1-timestamp-measured-from-00-00-00-00-15-October-
    return (uuid_.time * 1e-7 - (dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) -
                                 dt.datetime(1582, 10, 15)).total_seconds())
```

Usage:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> # Extract timestamp from a new Python UUID v1 instance.
>>> uuid1_unix_timestamp(uuid.uuid1())
1533834175.8219986
>>> # Convert timestamp from Python UUID v1 to Python datetime.
>>> timestamp = uuid1_unix_timestamp(uuid.uuid1())
>>> dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 9, 17, 3, 10, 122999)
>>> # Extract timestamp from a UUID v1 string.
>>> uuid_ = uuid.UUID('4101d7a1-9bf6-11e8-b86d-9cb6d0e37eb4')
>>> uuid1_unix_timestamp(uuid_)
1533834258.9699993
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that will generate a UUID1 from a given integer timestamp

Note that while timestamp part will stay static, a part of the uuid is still random.
You can pass the `clock_seq` value if you want the uuid to stay the same

```
import uuid

try:
    import unittest.mock as mock
except ImportError:
    import mock


def fixed_uuid1(timestamp, *args, **kwargs):
    """Returns a UUID1 from a fixed timestamp"""
    with mock.patch('uuid._uuid_generate_time', None), \
            mock.patch('uuid._last_timestamp', None), \
            mock.patch('time.time', return_value=timestamp):
        return uuid.uuid1(*args, **kwargs)


print(fixed_uuid1(0))
print(fixed_uuid1(0, clock_seq=0))
print(fixed_uuid1(1565627822.303553))
```